# python infinite loop blocking asyncio concurrent tasks

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

maybe i understood something wrong, but here is my problem.

As i have read in the documentary, you need to create tasks to execute them concurrently:

```
async def main():
x=1
lastman = deque([])
    while True:
        task1 = asyncio.create_task(get_salt())
        task2 = asyncio.create_taks(get_sugar_every10_secondes())

        await task1
        await task2

async def get_salt():
    salt = await salt.fetch()
    print(salt)

async def get_sugar_every10_secondes():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    sugar = await sugar.fetch()
    print(sugar)

 asyncio.get_even_loop().run_until_completed(main())
```

The problem is that i only get salt and sugar output every 10 secondes, but i want salt as fast as possible and sugar every 10 secondes. (py3.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    # ...
    await task1
    await task2
```

This part means:

1. await when task1 is done
2. then await when task2 is done
3. then continue loop

None of tasks will be recreated until both are done.

Instead you should create two tasks each of them calling own coroutine in `while True` loop. This way noen of them should wait other is done.

Something like this:

```
import asyncio
from collections import deque


async def do_constantly(coro_func):
    while True:
        await coro_func()


async def get_salt():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('salt')


async def get_sugar_every10_secondes():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('sugar')


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(do_constantly(get_salt))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(do_constantly(get_sugar_every10_secondes))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.run_forever()  # to keep tasks spawning
```

Comment: do you know how i could use the get_salt return value, to do something with it? like maybe: if(task1=="salt"): print('jep its for sure salt')

Comment: @User1010 easiest way is to create global variable and store salt's value there. `do_constantly` make update this variable after each loop iteration is ready.